# Android: Navigation Component and Instant app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-instant-apps, android-architecture-navigation

The Navigation Component doc encourages a single activity with multiple fragments.

How do we make this work with instant apps? How would they land directly in a fragment?

I'm thinking of a specific use case:
On the installed app, the user starts on the splash screen, logs in if necessary, then arrives on a home page which is made up of a BottomNavigation with three parts: Feature1, Feature2 and Feature3.
Each feature is a fragment, or a set of fragments and they live within the confine of the parent with the BottomNav.

Now would it be possible to create an instant app that opens directly in Feature3, which would mean without the parent BottomNAv. The feature would just be by itself?

Comment: I have the same exact question, I've tried to reach out to Google advocates with no success.

Comment: I have very similar UI on my App. Did you find solution to work with Navifation Component and Instant App?